Well-defined game stops
In Aaron Siegel's Combinatorial Game Theory, on pg. 75, he defines stops as:

Let $G$ be a short game. The Left stop $L(G)$ and the Right Stop $R(G)$ are defined recursively by
$ L(G) = \begin{cases} G & \text{if } G = \text{some number} \\
 \underset{G^{L}}{\max}(R(G^{L})) & \text{otherwise} \end{cases} $
$ R(G) = \begin{cases} G & \text{if } G = \text{some number} \\
 \underset{G^{R}}{\min}(L(G^{R})) & \text{otherwise} \end{cases} $

However, I have not encountered a proof where non-numbers must have non-empty left and right sets. In Aaron Siegel's CGSuite, he assumes that this will be true (where if it is not true, a non-sensical Integer.MIN_VALUE or Integer.MAX_VALUE is returned instead).
Is this fact always true?

If the right set is empty, $G = \{G^L | \}$, then $G$ equals the smallest integer which is greater than all of the $G^L$. (In chapter II, all games are assumed short, so there are only finitely many $G^L$, so this integer exists.)
If the left set is empty, $G = \{ | G^R\}$, then $G$ equals the largest integer which is less than all of the $G^R$.
These results follow from the simplicity theorem (Theorem 3.10) and Proposition 3.12.
